# Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given, although array appears properly formed?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm working with user data in WordPress, but I think this error is more of a general PHP issue on my end.

I use a function `wp_update_user()` which takes an array of keys and values corresponding to certain user fields, like `display_name`.

The code responsible looks as follows (note that I'm hardcoding the value for `display_name` for debugging purposes):

```
$returnValue = wp_update_user(array( 'ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => 'Test 123' ));
if (is_wp_error($returnValue)) {
    print_r($returnValue);
} else {
    echo "User update was a success, ID returned is " . $returnValue;
}
```

The if statement would output an error object if there is an error. However, the value is updating in the database as expected, and no error is returned from WP. The server, however, is giving me a series of warnings, which begin with `Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /srv/www/mysite.com/current/web/wp/wp-includes/user.php on line 1993`. I looked up the function `array_keys()` but as far as I can tell, I'm passing a correctly-formed array as required. This warning does stem from the `wp_update_user()` function.

As stated above, the actual code seems to work and do what I want it to do, so this warning isn't actually impeding any functionality. I suppose I can hide this warning output but in the interest of best practices I would like to get to the bottom of it. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the warning triggered from the wp_update_user function?, please show the rest of the error message. not `...` the code looks fine.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, it is triggered from that function. Just updated my post.

Comment: There is no call to `array_keys()` in the code you posted. Add to the post the code that triggers the error.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure its not the parameter you pass that is wrong , but an internal WP process.Try calling that with a plain integer as id of an already existing user

Comment: I've tried that - same exact behavior (functionality works as expected but I still see the same warning).

Comment: Meh ,then i guess you can do the following.Install xdebug and inseet a breakpoint or just do an echo at the error line in wp includes.Or just insert a @ at the function for error suppress and forget it muahah

Comment: Actually I just noticed something. If I pass the user ID in quotes, it updates correctly. If I pass it as a plain integer (as shown in the documentation example about this function), it doesn't update the user. I'm not sure if that's relevant to this issue or not, but is my only real lead right now.

Comment: Seems to be caused in get user contact methods function.If you go to line 1993 you see it does an array merge,it adds the default keys to the user keys.Thats in get_additional_user_keys function that takes a user as a parameter.Do a var dump on the parameter and check if the user was null.